# a boolean parameter OR string parameter for allowing a caller to set the sort order of a result set

Tags: sorting

I have searched for a "standard" on this issue but have not been able to find one. So, I thought I would ask the great community at SO.

The sort order of data can be either ascending or descending. The default is typically ascending I believe. When allowing folks access to data via an RPC or Rest call, does it make more sense to provide a bool parameter named "orderDesc" and if it is null or false, return the data in ascending order. If it is true return the data in descending order.

OR

Is it better to provide a string parameter named "sortOrder" and allow folks to send in the value of either "asc" or "desc".

I lean towards the bool parameter because I believe it simplifies the code, but, I am curious if I am in the minority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One other option is to use a sortBy parameter and allow values like +firstName or -firstName to indicate the column AND direction. This could then allow you to expand the API to allow for multi column sorting. i.e. api/employees?sortBy=-age,+salary. Finally sort order is also important when considering pagination. It seems to make sense to be consistent in the GET request for both

Comment: we ended up doing something similar to what you suggested here. thanks.